# export 'formatDate' (imported as 'formatDate') was not found in '@fullcalendar/react'

Tags: reactjs, plugins, compilation, calendar

When i compile this is the last thing i cant figure out. I believe it may have something to do with the version

I tried rewriting the function in the file from "

```
{formatDate(event.start, {
                        year: "numeric",
                        month: "short",
                        day: "numeric",
                      }"
```

To

```
 FullCalendar.formatDate( date, settings )
```

Also tried changing "@fullcalendar/react" to "@fullcalendar/core"

same results

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this module was removed from that package.
This is my workaround:

I removed the import in my header.

I created a new function:

```
const formatDate = (date) => {
    return new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", {
        year: "numeric",
        month: "short",
        day: "numeric",
    }).format(date);
};
```

then in my code, I called the function:

```
<Typography> {formatDate(event.start)} </Typography>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It is now importing from '@fullcalendar/core'

like this => import { formatDate } from '@fullcalendar/core'

Link to the docs: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/formatDate